# Create an UPDATE statement without primary key

Tags: c#, sql-server

My code is as follows:

```
"UPDATE Mytable SET Phone= '"+PhoneNumber+"', 
 Age= '"+Age+"' 
 Where Name= '"+Name+"'";
```

Now the name here is not unique nor is the primary key.
When the code searches for the match, it has to input the data in the latest record in descending order.

If the name list in the database table was:

1. Adam
2. Steve
3. **Paul**
4. Peter
5. Homer
6. **Paul**

The data has to fit in 'No.6-Paul' and not 'No.3-Paul'

Thanks a lot

Comment: "Now the name here is not unique nor is the primary key". Care to explain how the `Primary Key` is not unique?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To update through a known ordering, you could use a strategy to update through the same view or projection used to generate your original query, and provided that you are just updating data in one table:

```
WITH cteUpdate AS
(
   SELECT TOP 1 *
   FROM MyTable
   WHERE Name ='Paul'
   ORDER BY YourOrderColumnsHere DESC
)
UPDATE cteUpdate
   SET Phone= @PhoneNumber, Age= @Age;
```

Please remember to also parameterize your C# Code!

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/42df2/5)

However, note that this is vulnerable to concurrency issues, e.g. if another connection / user has already updated the record in the interim (e.g. since a button was clicked on screen), you might not be updating the `Paul` that you thought you were.

If you need a deterministic update, you don't have many options without a key. The best bet might be the optimistic concurrency hack, viz extending the WHERE to include ALL columns of the previously known value of the record, i.e.

```
UPDATE ... 
WHERE Name = 'Paul' 
  and Phone='{oldValueOfPhone}' 
  and Age = '{oldValueOfAge}';
```

Comment: Welcome! Promise me you'll parameterize :) Also, heed Raj's chirp that if you DO have a `PRIMARY KEY`, it must be unique, so therefore you'll have something infinitely preferable to use as a deterministic update!

Comment: I shall parametrize all my work right away! The project I am working on needs to update records with same names. Thanks again for the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
;with x as (
  select Phone, Age, row_number() over(partition by Name order by ID desc) as rn
  from MyTable
)
update x
set Phone= @PhoneNumber, Age=@Age
where Name= @Name and rn = 1;
```